# CLion: how to build locally, copy binary to remote and debug it with

Tags: remote-debugging, clion, gdbserver

Currently I run configuration "Build binary" in CLion, `scp` it to the remote machine, start gdbserver there for the binary, and then I switch to the "Debug binary" configuration and press the Debug button.

Is there any way to simplify/automate this in CLion? I can't even make the "Debug binary" call the "Build binary" configuration: since I'm pressing the "Debug" button, it will try to debug the "Build binary".

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, your goal is to build locally and debug remotely with gdbserver. There is a specific `Run|Debug Configuration` called `Remote GDB Server`. Basically, you should provide connection details and specify gdb, gdbserver with args. Than CLion with every debug started will rebuild the binary (if it have to), upload binary to the remote (if you want to), run gdbserver on remote and connect to it from you local.
For more details look at the description:
[Remote GDB Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-gdb-server.html)
Hope this will do the trick.